# JSON.NET how to create an index

Tags: c#, json.net

I have multiple strings and string-arrays inside my Model, where they're gathered inside a list. Code:

```
namespace ReinovaGrafieken.Models
 {
  [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
  public class Graphs
  {
    [JsonProperty]
     public string Names { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string[] AnswerHeaders { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string[] AnswersOne { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string[] AnswersTwo { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string[] AnswersThree { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string[] AnswersFour { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Questions { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string[] AnteOrPost { get; set; }
  }
 }
```

But what happens when I create my Json with the following code:

```
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(graphData);
```

Is that the json will be filled rather strangely.
If I fill up every string([]) once, I'll get 8 times Names, AnswerHeaders, etc. 
But every time only one value will be filled. The rest of the instances is empty. I know i can use

```
NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
```

But if I do that I can't use proper Indexes anymore, because the code will think every single Names, AnswerHeaders, etc, is a single index.

Current output:

```
"0":{  
  "questionName":null,
  "AnswerHeaders":null,
  "AnswersOne":null,
  "AnswersTwo":null,
  "AnswersThree":null,
  "AnswersFour":null,
  "Questions":"Vraag ante 11 & Vraag post 33",
  "AnteOrPost":null
 },
```

Expected output:

```
  "0":{  
"questionName": "Vraag 1",
"AnswerHeaders": "Wat vond u",
"AnswersOne": ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
"AnswersTwo": ["23","34","4","3"],
"AnswersThree":["34", "34", "5", "4", "2"].
"AnswersFour":["23","3","4","3","2"],
"Questions":"Vraag ante 11 & Vraag post 33",
"AnteOrPost": "Ante"
},
```

Comment: Can you share the expected JSON output and actual JSON output?

Comment: Added the expected and actual. The Json should be 29 instances long, but is actually 232 long ( 29 * 8)

Comment: In the expected output, I suppose you meant to quote the string values, otherwise it's not a valid JSON, so that can't be the expected output. Could you show us the source of the serialisation?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - I've just tried your code, and I got what I expected. It's unclear why you expect the answers to end up as an *integer* array when you've specified a *string* array too. (I suspect you don't need that many properties to demonstrate the problem though.)

Comment: @Kenneth, ah ye, that's meant to be quoted.

Comment: @Carlove JSON.NET won't emit `null` if the properties have data. Did you fill them? Are you serializing the *wrong* variable or instance perhaps? Post the code that creates the objects and serializes the string

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll look at the Minimal, Complete example in a bit. Yeah, I changed my strings to int arrays, as they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current output:

```
"0":{  
  "questionName":null,
  "AnswerHeaders":null,
  "AnswersOne":null,
  "AnswersTwo":null,
  "AnswersThree":null,
  "AnswersFour":null,
  "Questions":"Vraag ante 11 & Vraag post 33",
  "AnteOrPost":null
 },
```

Means that `JsonConvert` could not convert your array to json string **OR** it means that you didn't fill your array when serializing.

Make sure your json is properly filled by filling the fields with demo data:

```
AnswerHeaders = new string[] {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
```

and check to see the value when serialized, this will be a good starting point for your inquiry.

Comment: Hey Barr, I can fill my json "correctly" if I tell it to ignore null. Then I will get the expected output, but I can't index them correctly, anymore.

Comment: This is not correctly, because the null comes when the scenarios I stated happen in code. When serializing the json, nulls appear when no value is given or when a conversion is unable to take place due to misleading types. You only ignore nulls if you intend to have null values in your json that should be left out.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I was calling the Graphs class 8 times, instead of 1 time. Resulting into 232 strings for the Json. Afterwards I didn't have to give indexes anymore, either.